# Find all combinations of an ArrayList of ArrayLists of user defined objects

Tags: java, arraylist, nested-lists

I have defined a class `Note` that represents a way to play a certain note (two integers for the string and fret on a string instrument), and a class `Chord` which has an ArrayList of all the notes in that chord.

For every note that is played there may be multiple ways of playing that note so I have an ArrayList of Notes representing each possible way. In a chord there can be any number of notes so I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Notes. From this I want to create an ArrayList of chords with each possible way of playing the chord.

I have defined a constructor `Chord(ArrayList<Note> notes)`

eg:
Note A has 3 ways of being played and note B 2 ways of being played, from this I would want chords with:

[A1,B1], [A1,B2], [A2 B1], [A2 B2], [A3,B1], [A3,B2].

I have created a method that works under the assumption that there are always 3 notes played but can't think how to expand it to work for an unknown number

```
public static ArrayList<Chord> allPlayable(ArrayList<ArrayList<Note>> candidates)
{
    ArrayList<Chord> allPlayable = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < candidates.get(0).size(); i++)
    {
        Note n0 = candidates.get(0).get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < candidates.get(1).size(); j++)
        {
            Note n1 = candidates.get(1).get(j);

            for (int k = 0; k < candidates.get(2).size(); k++)
            {
                Note n2 = candidates.get(1).get(k);


                ArrayList<Note> chordNotes = new ArrayList<>();

                chordNotes.add(n0);
                chordNotes.add(n1);
                chordNotes.add(n2);

                allPlayable.add(new Chord(chordNotes));

            }
        }
    }

    return allPlayable;
}
```

Comment: What your question? What code have you tried? What errors do you get? If this is a homework question, this isn't the place to ask it.

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear. I am trying to make a method which returns an ArrayList of Chord objects, this ArrayList should have every possible combination of playing a chord with all the given notes.

if it was a 2d matrix of notes i would understand that a nested for loop could be used to cover every possible outcome however i am unsure of what to use as the size of all the ArrayLists are dynamic

Comment: You will still need to attempt some code and post it here. SO isn't meant to  write code for you. Give it a try and include your code and any errors your get.

Comment: I have created a solution for 3 notes, but don't know how to expand it to allow for dynamic size. I should clarify that I'm not asking for the solution, I simply don't know how to begin to create a solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

IT was suggested to me to use recursion - every for loop would be another recursive call and I came up with this answer

```
public static ArrayList<Chord> allPlayable(ArrayList<ArrayList<Note>> candidates)
{
    //this will be the inner ArrayList we are on 
    ArrayList<Note> current = new ArrayList();

    //the list of chords to return
    ArrayList<Chord> allPlayable = new ArrayList();

    allPlayableRecurse(candidates, 0, current, allPlayable);

    return allPlayable;
}
public static void allPlayableRecurse(ArrayList<ArrayList<Note>> candidates, int index, ArrayList<Note> chordNotes, ArrayList<Chord> allPlayable)
{
    ArrayList<Note> current = candidates.get(index);

    //for each note in the current array list of notes
    for (int i = 0; i < current.size(); i++)
    {
        chordNotes.add(current.get(i));

        //there are more notes to add
        if (index < candidates.size()-1)
        {
            //go to the next inner ArrayList
            allPlayableRecurse(candidates, index+1, chordNotes, allPlayable);
        }
        else//we have reached the last note
        {
            //add the chord to the list
            allPlayable.add(new Chord((ArrayList<Note>)chordNotes.clone()));
        }

        //we will now replace this note
        chordNotes.remove(chordNotes.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion, for example:

```
   List<List<Note>> combine(List<List<Note>> representations) {
        List<Note> options = representations.get(0);
        List<List<Note>> tails;
        if (representations.size()==1) {
            tails = new ArrayList<>();
            tails.add(Collections.emptyList());
        } else {
            tails = combine(representations.subList(1, representations.size()));
        }

        List<List<Note>> combinations = new ArrayList<>(options.size());
        for (Note note : options) {
            for (List<Note> tail : tails) {
                List<Note> chord = new ArrayList<>();
                chord.add(note);
                chord.addAll(tail);
                combinations.add(chord);
            }

        }
        return combinations;

    }

    public List<Chord> allPlayable(List<List<Note>> candidates) {

        List<List<Note>> combinations = combine(candidates);
        List<Chord> chords = new ArrayList<>(combinations.size());
        for (List<Note> notes : combinations) chords.add(new Chord(notes));
        return chords;
```

}

It is the old java7 style. It can be done easier with new Java8 functional operations but not sure if it is already your thing if you just started.